# Analyzing Function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function

Trying to analyze this snippet of code but not really sure what it does? How does this demonstrate how functions work in JS? Sorry for the newb question. Confused? Thanks.

```
function merge(root) {
    for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        for (var key in arguments[i]) {
            root[key] = arguments[i][key];
        }
    }
}

var merged = merge(
    {name: "Batou"},
    {city: "Niihama"},
    (activity: "Weights", min: 0, max: 35, points: 2500, scale: "sum"});

assert(merged.name === "Batou",
    "The original name is intact.");
assert(merged.max === 35,
    "The maximum number of sets is 35.");
```

Comment: What exactly do you not understand? Btw, your code contains some errors.

Comment: Sorry for the errors, not my code! I'm just trying to walk through the operations and understand whats happening. I am new to JavaScript (as you can tell) and trying to understand concepts of functions.

Comment: `merge` doesn't return `root`, so it doesn't do a whole lot, actually.

Comment: @Shmiddty, technically the `merge` function doesn't *need* to return `root`, as long as a reference to `root` is kept by the calling code. Obviously the usage of this function indicates that `root` should be returned.

Answer (score 2):

First, fix the three (syntax) errors:

- line 2: `I` to lowercase `i`
- line 6: You want to `return root;` from the function to make it work, else `undefined` would be assigned to `merged`
- line 12: `(` to `{`.

Apart from that, the code it quite simple. The [function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Functions) `merge` takes an arbitrary amount of parameters. It [iterates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) the [`arguments` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) from index 1 (i.e. not including the `root` parameter) and for each item it [enumerates its properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in), [copying](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators) their values to the `root` object. The [bracket syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators) is used to access the property values by their names.

So, `merge` *merges* all passed [objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) into the first object, overwriting already existing keys.

Answer (score 0):

This will merge two or more objects into one.

`{name: "Batou"}`

Is a shortcut to:

```
var obj = new Object();
obj.name = "Batou";
```

Inside a function `arguments` is a array of arguments passed at call, and you can change properties in objects like you do in a array but using string:

```
obj["name"] = "Batou";
```

The `assert` keyword will check if a condition is true, it's used for debug proposes.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I see 3 errors on your code: that uppercase `I` should be `i`; `(activity:` should be `{activity:`; the function should `return root`.

If you fix that, the function is supposed to merge all objects passed to it into a single object. You're passing 3 objects:

- `{name: "Batou"}`
- `{city: "Niihama"}`
- `{activity: "Weights", min: 0, max: 35, points: 2500, scale: "sum"}`

Given those 3 objects as an input, the function returns a merged object:

```
{
    name: "Batou",
    city: "Niihama",
    activity: "Weights", 
    min: 0,
    max: 35, 
    points: 2500, 
    scale: "sum"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has an Object called `arguments` which holds all arguments, a function was called with.

This

```
function merge(root) {
    for (var i = 1; I < arguments.length; i++) {
        for (var key in arguments[i]) {
            root[key] = arguments[i][key];
        }
    }
}
```

Basically takes multiple arguments and puts all properties of the other arguments (starting with the second one) into the first object which was passed to the function

Speaking :

this is the first argument passed to the funciton:
`{name: "Batou"}`

Then it loops through the properties of the other 2 obbjects

```
{city: "Niihama"},
(activity: "Weights", min: 0, max: 35, points: 2500, scale: "sum"});
```

And adds their properties to the first one, resulting in this

```
{name: "Batou",
city: "Niihama",
activity: "Weights", min: 0, max: 35, points: 2500, scale: "sum"}
```

Answer (score 0):

for the code to work as written, it would need to be modified:

```
function merge(root) {
    for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        for (var key in arguments[i]) {
            root[key] = arguments[i][key];
        }
    }
    return root; // without this line, "merged" below will always be undefined. 
}

var merged = merge(
    {name: "Batou"},
    {city: "Niihama"},
    {activity: "Weights", min: 0, max: 35, points: 2500, scale: "sum"});

assert(merged.name === "Batou",
    "The original name is intact.");
assert(merged.max === 35,
    "The maximum number of sets is 35.");
```

Or, it would need to be used differently:

```
function merge(root) {
    for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        for (var key in arguments[i]) {
            root[key] = arguments[i][key];
        }
    }
}

var merged = {name: "Batou"};
merge(
    merged,
    {city: "Niihama"},
    {activity: "Weights", min: 0, max: 35, points: 2500, scale: "sum"});

assert(merged.name === "Batou",
    "The original name is intact.");
assert(merged.max === 35,
    "The maximum number of sets is 35.");
```